# Configuring hibernate connection_finder with Oracle Spatial in Spring Boot

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, oracle-spatial

I use Hibernate Spatial with Oracle database (12c and 18g). As a framework here is Spring Boot 2.x and HikariCP as a connection pool.
The issue is, that for Hikari and this Oracle Spatial features I had to create custom class (connection finder) that needs to be setup via:

`hibernate.spatial.connection_finder`

It works all right if I pass this option as VM option in IntelliJ. But if I put this into application.properties, it is not picked up and configured properly. I also tried this key but with no luck:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.spatial.connection_finder`

Is this config key somehow not supported by Spring Boot or should it be configured in code instead?

Thanks for any inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct key is;
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.spatial.connection_finder